# font size discrepancy between tumblr and hard coded

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have an odd issue... When im comparing two elements on a website I have coded on my server compared to a tumblr site I created on their server, there is a 2px font size discrepancy.

both sites have this code:

```
<body>
<h1>Text</h1>
```

I have no font sizes set anywhere but both body css codes are:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 4100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and both h1 codes are:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0.67em 0 0.67em 0;
}
```

for whatever reason, the tumblr site has a 2px font size difference (smaller). is there any known reason why?

EDIT
I've added a base font size of 16px to both html attributes, however there still seems to be about a 2px difference. Some links to the sources:

Server:
http://goo.gl/PfyQ6r

Tumblr:
http://goo.gl/5gDfp4

Comment: Could you link us to the two examples? font size 100% can be affected by inheritance.

Comment: what's the font-size declaration in the css for the `html` element? You can use the developer tools in your browser to view the calculated values.

Comment: I removed the Tumblr tag. Tumblr doesn't server any CSS that would alter the font size. In Chrome, both sites are showing a font size of `16px`: http://i.imgur.com/j0InKk3.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumblr's global.css file as AR7 noted is set to 14px, the default html font size in most browsers is 16px but is also user definable.

```
html, body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue","HelveticaNeue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #444;
}
```

Your question code example sets the `body` `font-size` as inherited from its parent (`html`) at 100%. If you did not specify the `html` font-size it would inherit the browser's defined default font-size to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Font size by default is 16px I believe and is usually defined in the body.

Popular frameworks like bootstrap have the font size set as 14px in the body.

That's probably why there's a difference because the default font size is what is used when you specify 100%. Tumblr's own css files, which are completely unrelated to yours, specify it as 14px by default.

Comment: Whilst this may be true there is no evidence in the original question that might indicate that this is the case.  This "answer" would have been better as a comment.

Comment: My apologies for not posting any code, but if you go look this is actually the case.

Comment: No code is necessary and, again, there is nothing in the question to indicate any Base font size in the OP's non-Tumblr code.  That said it does seem that this is the likely culprit.